# Callable with Executor Service to get the decision

Tags: java, multithreading, priority-queue, executorservice

I have one scenario. In which I have one table in which candidate data is available. (Candidate name, experience, location preference, salary). I have to fetch the result from the database.

I want to apply below processes on the list
1) If salary <5 then print the candidate details
2) If Experience is > 2 then print the candidate details
3) If Location preference is Mumbai then print the candidate details

Whoever passed with above conditions store that candidate name in priority queue. I have to use executor service to achieve this.

I am new to threading and Executor framework.How to achieve this?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: We'd be glad to help you understand what is wrong with your code.  Show us some code that you have written, but which does not behave in the way that you expected it to behave.  Tell us what you _thought_ it would do, tell us what it actually did instead, and we will try to explain the reason why and maybe suggest a better way.

Comment: @Spotted I have tried Callable instead of Runnable interface so that it can return matched criteria. So, I have created 3 classes with Callable implementation, to validate each scenario. I will update the post with code.